# extracting text using Apache Tika then getting frequently occurring words after removing stopwords

Tags: java, lucene, apache-tika, word-count, stop-words

i have extracted text for  sample.pdf file using Tika and lucene and i tried to remove stopwords then i get the wordcount of remaining words(excluding stopwords) from the text.

my sample.pdf contains

```
This is java related information it contains java prg.
```

Below is my code

```
String[] stopwords ={"a", "about", "above", "above", "across", "after", "afterwards", "again", "against", "all", "almost", 
                        "alone", "along", "already", "also","although","always","am","among", "amongst", "amoungst", "amount",  "an", "and", 
                        "another", "any","anyhow","anyone","anything","anyway", "anywhere", "are", "around", "as",  "at", "back","be","became", 
                        "because","become","becomes", "becoming", "been", "before", "beforehand", "behind", "being", "below", "beside", "besides", 
                        "between", "beyond", "bill", "both", "bottom","but", "by", "call", "can", "cannot", "cant", "co", "con", "could", "couldnt",
                        "cry", "de", "describe", "detail", "do", "done", "down", "due", "during", "each", "eg", "eight", "either", "eleven","else",
                        "elsewhere", "empty", "enough", "etc", "even", "ever", "every", "everyone", "everything", "everywhere", "except", "few", 
                        "fifteen", "fify", "fill", "find", "fire", "first", "five", "for", "former", "formerly", "forty", "found", "four", "from", 
                        "front", "full", "further", "get", "give", "go", "had", "has", "hasnt",
                        "have", "he", "hence", "her", "here", "hereafter", "hereby", "herein", "hereupon", "hers", "herself", 
                        "him", "himself", "his", "how", "however", "hundred", "ie", "if", "in", "inc", "indeed", "interest", "into", 
                        "is", "it", "its", "itself", "keep", "last", "latter", "latterly", "least", "less", "ltd", "made", "many", 
                        "may", "me", "meanwhile", "might", "mill", "mine", "more", "moreover", "most", "mostly", "move", "much", "must", 
                        "my", "myself", "name", "namely", "neither", "never", "nevertheless", "next", "nine", "no", "nobody", "none", 
                        "noone", "nor", "not", "nothing", "now", "nowhere", "of", "off", "often", "on", "once", "one", "only", "onto", 
                        "or", "other", "others", "otherwise", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", "over", "own","part", "per", "perhaps",
                        "please", "put", "rather", "re", "same", "see", "seem", "seemed", "seeming", "seems", "serious", "several", "she",
                        "should", "show", "side", "since", "sincere", "six", "sixty", "so", "some", "somehow", "someone", "something", 
                        "sometime", "sometimes", "somewhere", "still", "such", "system", "take", "ten", "than", "that", "the", "their", 
                        "them", "themselves", "then", "thence", "there", "thereafter", "thereby", "therefore", "therein", "thereupon", 
                        "these", "they", "thickv", "thin", "third", "this", "those", "though", "three", "through", "throughout", "thru", 
                        "thus", "to", "together", "too", "top", "toward", "towards", "twelve", "twenty", "two", "un", "under", "until", 
                        "up", "upon", "us", "very", "via", "was", "we", "well", "were", "what", "whatever", "when", "whence", "whenever",
                        "where", "whereafter", "whereas", "whereby", "wherein", "whereupon", "wherever", "whether", "which", "while", 
                        "whither", "who", "whoever", "whole", "whom", "whose", "why", "will", "with", "within", "without", "would", "yet",
                        "you", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","1.","2.","3.","4.","5.","6.","11",
                        "7.","8.","9.","12","13","14","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
                        "terms","CONDITIONS","conditions","values","interested.","care","sure",".","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","{","}","[","]",":",";",",","<",".",">","/","?","_","-","+","=",
                        "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
                        "contact","grounds","buyers","tried","said,","plan","value","principle.","forces","sent:","is,","was","like",
                        "discussion","tmus","diffrent.","layout","area.","thanks","thankyou","hello","bye","rise","fell","fall","psqft.","http://","km","miles"};

                Map map = new TreeMap();
                   File file1 = new File("C://sample.pdf");
                   InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file1);           
                   Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                  BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(10*1024*1024);
                  AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();       
                  parser.parse(input, handler, metadata);
                  Document doc = new Document();
                doc.add(new Field("contents",handler.toString(),Field.Store.NO,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                String result = doc.toString();
                String[] res=result.split(" ");
                for (int i=0;i<res.length;i++)
                {
                int flag=1;
                    String s1=res[i].toLowerCase();

                  for(int j=0;j<stopwords.length;j++){
                      if(s1.equals(stopwords[j]))
                          {
                          flag=0;
                          }
                    if(flag!=0)
                  {
                     if (s1.length() > 0) { 

                         Integer frequency = (Integer) map.get(s1);
                              if (frequency == null) {
                                frequency = ONE;
                              } else {

                                int value = frequency.intValue();
                                frequency = new Integer(value + 1);
                            }
                              map.put(s1, frequency);
                             }  
                               }
                }
                }
                input.close();
                System.out.println("Finalresult:"+map);
                 }
```

i'm getting following output which is not correct

```
Finalresult:{contains=456, document<indexed,tokenized<contents:this=456, information=456, is=139, it=140, java=912, prg=456, related=456}
```

i should get the following output

```
information=1,java=2, prg=1, related=1
```

can u please suggest me to get the required output.
thanks

Comment: Looks like you just need to loop over the map at the end, and print out the keys + values in your desired format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an example of why consistent code formatting is important.  Good indentation would probably make the cause of this issue much more obvious to you.

```
for (int i=0;i<res.length;i++)
{
    int flag=1;
    String s1=res[i].toLowerCase();

    for(int j=0;j<stopwords.length;j++)
    {
        if(s1.equals(stopwords[j]))
        {
            flag=0;
        }
        // -------- We are still looping through stopwords!  This for loop should be closed here! ---------
        if(flag!=0)
        {
            if (s1.length() > 0) 
            { 
                //Now this is going to add to the list for every entry in stopwords, until we find a match!
                Integer frequency = (Integer) map.get(s1);
                if (frequency == null) 
                {
                    frequency = ONE;
                } else 
                {
                    int value = frequency.intValue();
                    frequency = new Integer(value + 1);
                }
                map.put(s1, frequency);
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

You have 456 entries in stopwords, as we can see.  The behavior you're seeing is all due to the lack of a `}`